# Minimum value of unknown exponents for a perfect cube

Tags: number-theory

The following question showed up in an aptitude test I took.

> If $N = 2197^P × 144^2 × 2^R × 3^S$ is the perfect cube of a natural
>   number, where $P$, $R$ and $S$ are distinct positive integers, then find the
>   minimum value of $(P + R + S)$.

I solved it as follows:
[My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4r1I.jpg)

However, the correct answer is 6 as per the answer key released. Could anyone please tell where am I going wrong?

Here is the solution provided by the testing agency:
[Provided solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxpLp.png)

Comment: The answer you provide appears to be $4$ as well, no?

Comment: @lulu- It was a mistake. The answer key shows 6 as the answer. I corrected it. Apologies.

Comment: Oh, the problem is that  $P,Q,R$ are required to be distinct.

Comment: Maybe. Let me just also attach the image of their solution.

Comment: No need, $6$ is correct.  I initially missed the requirement that $P,Q,R$ had to be distinct.

Comment: Oh! I missed that too. I wonder when I'll stop making such mistakes. :(
Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty old and (obviously) I still make mistakes like that.  It's a problem with puzzle questions...if the question arises naturally then it's a lot more natural to keep track of all the requirements.

Comment: I agree. But in an exam like GRE/GMAT, such mistakes can make a lot of difference for me. Alas!

Answer (score 1):

$$2197 = 13^3$$
$$144 = 2^4 3^2$$

exponent of $13$ is $3P$

exponent of $2$ is $4 + R$

exponent of $3$ is $2+S$

So $P$ is $1,2,3,4,5...$

$R$ is $2,5,8,...$

$S$ is $1,4,7,...$

If $P$ is $1,2$ we need a second choice, best would be $S=4,$ but then $P+R \geq 3$ regardless, so sum is at least $7$

With $P=3, R=2, S=1 $ we get sum down to $6,$ and we cannot do better since $R+S \geq 3$